# How linkers work

Tags: linker, executable, exe, portable-executable

I need to understand how linkers work and how a linker makes an .exe with all its different sections and segments. To be more precise, I wanna be atleast able to make an .exe which contains the following code, with my hands using a hex editor.

```
int main()
{
}
```

Please suggest me some necessary reading. I have Linkers & Loaders by John Levine.

Answer (score 4):

Ian Lance Taylor wrote a new ELF linker, called `gold`. He described the general tasks that linkers do in a series of [blog posts](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/38).

This is different in details from what a PE linker does, but the general ideas are all the same (and same as in "Linkers & Loaders".

> I wanna be atleast able to make an .exe which contains the following code, with my hands using a hex editor

I am not sure why you want a linker in that case. Read the [description of PE file format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx), construct the necessary headers, write a tiny `.text` section containing `xor %eax,%eax; ret`, set the entry point to that section, ..., profit?

Answer (score 1):

How (static) linkers work:
Take all necessary object files (module), merging/combining/flattening the addresses so that inter-module calls are possible and correct, structuring them to fulfill the executable format requirements, and perhaps do link time optimizations.

To create an executable (note that here I'm not referring to any specific format), you have to know the executable format, usually consists of headers and sections, plus any required startup code (compilers usually already provided this as an object file, precompiled). For PE (.exe) files, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) has a good explanation.